# Open Layers 3 import geojson on Firefox always results in XML Parsing Error (yet works fine)

Tags: firefox, openlayers-3

When importing a geojson vector layer into OL3 the following error always appears in FireFox only:

```
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed Location:
```

This makes no difference to the running of the web application, I'd just like to know if anybody knows why this error is thrown in FireFox using standard OL3 functionality.

You can see this happen if you drag and drop a geojson into the demo here and observe the console in FireFox:

http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/drag-and-drop-image-vector.html?q=geojson

Or if you add a layer as follows:

```
var layer_to_return = new ol.layer.Vector({
       source: new ol.source.Vector({
         url: "MY/PATH/AND/GEOJSON.geojson",
         format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()              
        })
  });

 map.addLayer(layer_to_return);
```

The following is a simple geojson extract to use as a demo:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          2.4609375,
          48.45835188280866
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Your problem probably comes out of your geojson file. Unless you provide a sample of it we can really help you.

Comment: Could be, but this is quite unlikely because the error doesn't stop anything working, and it only shows in FireFox, and the GeoJsons are created using very common tools (like QGIS).  Having said that, I'll provide a demo geojson as soon as I get chance and update my question

Comment: My local geojson file works perfect when dropping it on the example you provide. So I am pretty sure that this is your problem.

Comment: I have added a single point in geojson format to my question.  I am very surprised you have no error.  In all of my files I get an error, and with the geojson added in the question which is from an online generator for geojson I also get the error.  Are you looking in the console and are you using FireFox?

Comment: I do save the geojson snip you provide , in a text file and save it local. Then I drop it in  the map using the example you provide. Everything works as a charm.

Comment: Yes it works, I actually have never said it doesn't work, its the error in the console I'm referring to in FireFox.

Comment: So everything works as a charm, but you just have an error on firebug and you want to know what the error is?

Comment: Yes, to be honest that's in my question, it does say it works fine and makes no difference to the running application. Its just weird how its in FireFox only

Comment: Ok, I dont think this is something you should worry about. It may be a firefox bug.

Comment: If you have a lot of layers, say 12, then you have 12 lines of errors appearing in the console, I would like to know if anybody in the community knows why FireFox has a problem with OL3's geojson reader, clearly containing an XML parsing element.

Comment: Maybe too late but if you change the extension of your `geojson` to `json` the error disappears

Comment: Thanks @pavlos, that's the correct answer.